# Too many open files with manager.List

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to speed up my parser in AWS Lambda Python.

It works fine local, but when I try it on the lambda I the error stated below. Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

```
 {   "errorMessage": "[Errno 24] Too many open files",   "errorType":
 "OSError",   "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 64, in lambda_handler\n    p.start()\n",
     "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py\", line 112, in start\n    self._popen = self._Popen(self)\n",
     "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 223, in _Popen\n    return
 _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)\n",
     "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 277, in _Popen\n    return Popen(process_obj)\n",
     "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py\", line 20, in __init__\n    self._launch(process_obj)\n",
     "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py\", line 69, in _launch\n    parent_r, child_w = os.pipe()\n"   ] }
```

My code looks like this:

```
def parse(item, L):
    r = requests.get(item[0], headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'},
                     cookies={'name': 'Parser',
                              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'})
    if (r.status_code == 200):
        if item[1] not in L:
            L.append([r.text, r.status_code, item[1]])
    else:
        L.append([None, r.status_code, item[1]])

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Make DB Connection

    with Manager() as manager:
        L = manager.list()  # <-- can be shared between processes.
        processes = []

        for item in sqlSelectVars:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=parse, args=(item, L))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()

        for process in processes:
            process.join()

        # Commit my parsed values to the DB with PyMySQL
        try:
            cursor.executemany(sqlUpdateRawHtml, L)
            cursor.connection.commit()
```

Comment: Could you show us what you do in `parse`? It's really helpful for us.

Comment: @LiuChang I've added my parsing code

Answer (score 0):

Just according to your description. I guess the reason is that **you create too many processes**.

From the Lambda documentation [AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html), we could get:

> File descriptors: 1,024
>
> Execution processes/threads: 1,024

So this part needs to be changed:

```
        for item in sqlSelectVars:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=parse, args=(item, L))
```

On the other hand, you want to "use multiprocessing to speed up my parser". In fact, if you just **compute in `parse`**, too many processes are useless. Instead, there's more overhead in process creation.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this? I've upped my file descriptors, but I'm parsing entries in the 10.000's at a time. So after about 500 processes, my file descriptor overloads and shuts the function down with an error. I've added my parsing code.

Comment: @SomeName First, looks you send `GET` request in `parse` so multiprocessing will work well for you. Then my advice is that you could set the maximum number of the processes running in parallel such as **100** (depends on you). You could using `multiprocessing.Pool` https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html.

Comment: AWS Lambda does not support Pool :/ @LiuChang

Comment: All right. Could try to "implement it" by your self? Such as using a nested for loop.@SomeName

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough understanding of multiprocessing to create that implementation

Comment: Emmmm in fact, you don't need really "implement it". For example you could easily split your `sqlSelectVars` into ten or some parts by index, then use a for loop to run five times.@SomeName